# IOS Swift: Pass data to another controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass data from one view controller to another.... I have a collection view in the first view controller which is populated dynamically with an array and want it so that when an item is clicked... it opens up the second view controller (which I've done) but sends along data (in this case an array)

Ive looked into core data, but after trying to implement it thought it might be a bit "overkill" for such a basic function? (or am i wrong?)

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Have you tried using segues?

Comment: Assuming you are using segues then `prepareForSegue` is the best way to do this. You override this in your initial view controller and are passed in a `UIStoryboardSegue` which has a `segue.destinationViewController` which you can use to set any data on that controller

Comment: Just set a property on the target view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I am using:

    `var itemViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("projectViewController") as UIViewController`

    `self.presentViewController(itemViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

is there anyway I can pass data similar to the segues?

Hi @jeffamaphone, how would I set a property on the target controller from my initial view controller?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Ok so i just tried something.... I set a variable in my app delegate file and then in my other controllers accessed it like this: `let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate);
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!;
        println(appDelegate.test)`

it works...but is it ok to use the app delegate like this?

Thanks

Comment: `itemViewController.myData = someDataIWantToPass;`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        // pass data to next view
}
```

Or NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(VALUE, forKey:YOUR_KEY)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! didn't have much luck trying to implement the NSUserDefaults, any ideas on the comments I left above?

Thanks